# Implementación de hilos: windows vs linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, hilos, jvm

Hace un tiempo hice un mini proyecto de P2P en Java y probándolo en diferentes sistemas operativos vi que en un Ubuntu 16.04 tardaba mucho más en descargar que en un Windows 8.1, cosa que me pareció muy extraña.

Comentándoselo a un profesor, me dijo que quizá sería la forma que tienen ambos sistemas de implementar los hilos dependiendo de si extienden de Thread o si implementan Runnable. Esta respuesta no me convenció mucho, pero tampoco he encontrado información que verifique o desmienta esto.

¿Alguno sabe a qué podría deberse? No vería lógico que la implementación de la JVM en ambos OS's diera diferencias tan grandes.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Eso es una pregunta muy interesante, pero para revisar el tema cientificamente se necesita el código que usaste y hay que armar un contexto de pruebas que es capaz de aislar las diferencias. Los SO distintos corrieron en la misma maquina, en la misma red bajo las mismas condiciónes? se tomaban medidas para asegurarse que las diferencias no existieron a causa de coincidencia o de condiciones temporales de la red? Espero que puedes proveer más informaciones. Voto para el cierre por mientras para darte el tiempo de refinar la pregunta antes que llegan especulaciones silvestres.

Comment: Informaciónes relevantes: Versión de Java usado, VM usado, condiciónes de red, código para el envío y recibo de datos sobre TCP o UDP, procesadora usada, numero de nucleos de procesadora, hardware general, se usaban drivers genericos o desde el productor de la hardware, especialmente para NIC y procesadora. Quizas a otros se le ocurre más.

Comment: En otros lenguajes de programación he encontrado diferencias notables entre Linux y Windows al hacer descargas masivas de datos que al final han estado relacionado con la gestión de los sockets (p.ej. cantidad de caché que se les asigna). Puede ser literalmente cualquier cosa. Si quieres comparar los threads de Linux contra los de Windows tienes que eliminar cualquier otra variable (incluyendo comunicaciones en red).